# Can't use nestjs-i18n with custom structure

Tags: internationalization, nestjs

My project structure is this:

```
root
├── backend (nest cli)
├── frontend
└── shared
    └── translations
        ├── en.json
        ├── no.json
        └── nl.json
```

I am trying to use '[nestjs-i18n](https://nestjs-i18n.com/)'. Where their folder structure in the docs are:

```
...
src
└── i18n
    ├── en
    │   ├── events.json
    │   └── test.json
    └── nl
        ├── events.json
        └── test.json
```

Is it possible to implement this package following my language file structure?
Its actually confusing in their documentation that if its required to follow their structure and the folder 'i18n'.

I have imported the module in app.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    I18nModule.forRoot({
      fallbackLanguage: 'en',
      loaderOptions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), '../shared/translations'),
        watch: true,
      },
      resolvers: [TenantLanguageResolver],
    }),
  ],
```

But whenever I'm trying to access it like this:

```
 const trans = await i18n.t('roles_help_text');
```

Getting the error:

```
ERROR [I18nService] Translation "roles_help_text" in "en" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nestjs-i18n doesn't provide the custom loader at present. So I have followed its strict file and folder naming structure. I haven't used any custom resolver to resolve language. Just added the language files in the assets array like the following:

```
// nest-cli.json

assets": [
  {
    "include": "../../shared/translations/en.json",
    "watchAssets": true,
    "outDir": "dist/i18n/en"
  },
  {
    "include": "../../shared/translations/no.json",
    "watchAssets": true,
    "outDir": "dist/i18n/no"
  }
]
```

Upon running the nest application, you will find the language files in the `dist` folder like the nestjs-i18n package wants them to be, inside their own nested folders:

```
dist
└── i18n
    ├── en
    │   └── en.json
    │── no
        └── no.json
```